# JQuery ajax call returns json data - good. How do we grab each piece of data so query can act on it?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Doing an ajax call to a page to grab 5 pieces of data.  3 images as filenames, 2 statuses as numbers 1/0.  End game is to use this data to instruct jquery to change out 3 divs with the images as a result of the ajax call.  So am trying to get a grip on these items to hand them off to a function that will swap out these divs.  Issue thus far is grabbing the data pieces into a format whereby I can manipulate them.  Values to vars....

Return data seems fine.  Formatted correctly.  Actual return example:

```
[
{"optiontext" : "spin1", "optionvalue" : "brown_anna.jpg"},
{"optiontext" : "spin2", "optionvalue" : "crada_amberly.jpg"},
{"optiontext" : "spin3", "optionvalue" : "ginda_marlins.jpg"},
{"optiontext" : "SID", "optionvalue" : "1"},
{"optiontext" : "HOT", "optionvalue" : "1"}
]
```

Called by - and just outputting them as a list - How does one obtain this data in distinct pieces  as vars for a future query image swap?

```
dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        var winns="<ul>";
        $.each(data, function(i,n){
        winns+="<li>"+n["optionvalue"]+"</li>";
        });
        winns+="</ul>";
        $('#message').append(winns);
        }
```

Any help greatly appreciated - its been days......  Does not have to be JSON data either.  At this point will try anything to get this charity project done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {

        $("#div1").append($("<img/>").attr("src", data[0].optionvalue));
        $("#div2").append($("<img/>").attr("src", data[1].optionvalue));
        $("#div3").append($("<img/>").attr("src", data[2].optionvalue));

    }
```

Comment: Nice.  Now that I see it this way its so obvious. This is SO much cleaner than my increment loop - which although it worked was 700% more verbose.  Thank you thank you osi.